# How to use curly brackets in npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, npm, mkdir

I want to run this simple command in an npm script called `prepare_build`:

```js
...
scripts: {
  "prepare_build" : "mkdir -p dist/lib/{js,css}"
}
...
```

running `npm run prepare_build` would create a single directory `dist/lib/{js,css}` whereas running the command in the console would create both `dist/lib/js` and `dist/lib/css`.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Note:**

- *I am aware of Gulp, Grunt, and other build systems WHICH I don't want to use*
- OS Interoperability is not of concern here. Linux is the main target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `{js,css}` syntax is neither a feature of mkdir, nor is it a feature of the OS. It is a feature of your shell (probably bash). So in order to interpret it you need to execute a shell that can understand that syntax.

The following will probably work but is untested:

```
scripts: {
  "prepare_build" : "bash -c 'mkdir -p dist/lib/{js,css}'"
}
```

This executes bash which transforms the command into:

```
mkdir -p dist/lib/js dist/lib/css
```

before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

When using the npm scripts there tend to be certain quirks that occur, especially when trying to create npm scripts that work on Win, Linux and Mac.  It is often most pragmatic to find workarounds.  In your case I would recommend installing the [mkdirp package](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) `npm install mkdirp --save-dev` and then the following will work:

```
scripts: {
  "prepare_build" : "mkdirp dist/lib/js dist/lib/css"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But we're back to square one! I wanted to make use of curly brackets and os Interoperability is not a big concern here. I will update the question now.